# Unable to switch between UIViewControllers using storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am new to objective C so please forgive me if this is a stupid question (and I have searched!)

I am using storyboards in xcode (4.4.1) and I have 2 UIViewControllers
I am trying to programmatically switch between them (not sure if that's the right terminology?)

```
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BookingView"];
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

The above code works perfectly later on in my project, but I when i try call if in an if() in my viewdidload method in the first UIViewController it doesn't work. Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't perform such task in the viewDidLoad: method.
You're trying to present a view controller modally on top of another that's only been allocated in memory and loaded, but it's not visible yet. That means your presentation won't work. You should move your code to viewDidAppear:

I recommend you to read this guide to learn the basics about view controller delegation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457

Comment: Thanks alex, i thought it might be something like that since it is working in an IBAction but not in the viewDidLoad. Should I just call another (custom) method from my viewDidLoad or from my viewDidAppear method? Thanks!

Comment: never mind my last comment, works in the viewDidAppear. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I guess what you're doing is to check a condition and depending on the result, you present or not a viewcontroller modally on top of another one. There's no difference really, and calling another different method would be more for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `self.storyboard` instead of `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];`?

Assuming that all your view controllers are from the same storyboard :)